# Lua function to convert windows paths to unix paths

Tags: lua

I am stuck with the eternal problem of windows using backslashes as path separators. I would like a Lua function which converts windows paths to unix paths.

1. I know I can assign a path to a variable by escaping the backslash e.g.

   filename = "P:\\user\\scripts\\config.lua"
2. I know this can be done using different string delimiters e.g.

   filename = [[P:\user\scripts\config.lua]]
3. I know I can't use string.gsub because the single backslash is either removed, or interpreted as an escape sequence, before being passed to gsub.

So using windows I have a problem when I assign a filename to a variable as the string contain single backslashes e.g.

```
filename = arg[0]
filename = debug.getinfo(2, "S").source:sub(2)
```

How can I convert this string to a unix style string with forward slashes?

```
function unixpath(filename)
    if filename~=nil then

    else
        return nil
    end
end

print(unixpath(arg[0]))
print(unixpath(debug.getinfo(2, "S").source:sub(2)))
print(unixpath([[P:\user\scripts\config.lua]]))
```

Comment: `io.open([[E:/TEMP/test]])` works on Lua 5.1 and WXP - why you need to convert? Unix don't have drive P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works for me:

```
$ lua
Lua 5.3.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2017 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> w = "c:\\windows\\system32"
> w
c:\windows\system32
> w:gsub("\\", "/")
c:/windows/system32     2
```

Comment: Thanks "return filename:gsub("\\","/")" works for all my test cases.

Comment: Do not forget that `gsub` returns 2 value. Some time it is important